# Sending Email through SmtpClient smtp.office365.com Generating Error in ASP.Net, C# web forms

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, exchange-server, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Anyone can help please.

I am using the following code for sending email from my ASP.Net, C# web forms application which generating the error. The same code is working for other application. My domain name contains a hyphen in it (-). Is that the reason? Do I need to see email configuration or server/domain level settings? Please help.

```
string smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com";
int port = 587;
using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
{
    using (SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtpServer))
    {
        mail.From = new MailAddress(_emailIDFrom);
        mail.To.Add(_emailIDTo);
        mail.Subject = _subject;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = _emailBody;
        SmtpServer.Port = port;
        SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_emailIDFrom, _emailIDFromPassword);
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        try
        {
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My Tls code in Global.asax Application_Start as follows

```
if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.HasFlag(SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) == false)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
}
```

ERROR--
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. Error: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [DXXP273CA0023.AREP273.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

Comment: anyone can help me for this pls?

Comment: have you fixed this already?